# changing the x,y axis points for SAPUI 5 Bubble Chart

Tags: charts, sapui5

Bubble charts are bordered on X and Y axis and by defualt start at 0,0, how can I reset defualt to change this value to 5,5  Y axis border should flow from gridline point 5 and x axis should flow from gridline 5 as well. and i want to destroy other gridlines on the chart.

Been checking but can t find any solution on SAPUI5 or OpenUI5 documentations

Thansk in advance

Comment: Nothing, I only did some search with no results, hence I asked, However, using CSS Background Image is another optioin that does not play right

Answer (score 1):

I have an example from line chart, but I think it also applies to your bubble chart, they key is the "scale" attribute in constructor of the yAxis / xAxis:

```
    var lineChart = new sap.viz.ui5.Line({
        width : "800px",
        height : "600px",
        dataset : oDataset,
        yAxis : {
            isIndependentMode : false,
            gridline : {
                showFirstLine : true,
                showLastLine : true,
                // type : sap.viz.ui5.types.Axis_gridline_type.dotted
            },
             scale : {
                 fixedRange : true,
                 minValue : 1300.0,
                 maxValue : 1800.0
                 }
        },
        legendGroup : legendPosition,
    });
```

For destroying other lines, you need an event: I think the only one possible is selectData(oControlEvent). Then fetch the data from the chart via .getModel().getProperty("/"); --> you receive your data as JSON. Then delete the line-data and rebind the data to the chart, then refresh or reload the chart (btw. no I cannot provide an code example unless coding everything on my own, so please provide any code).

Regards, zY

Comment: Setting minValue to 5 results in starting at 5 instead of 0 as seen in the first chart i the picture http://i.snag.gy/9NMFK.jpg the code I use is here http://pastebin.com/sNwVG9bV

Comment: And as you can see I am using the scatter VIZ object, I cant even see how to create a bubble chart, not a scatter chat, currently I use var mainCoyBubbleChart = new sap.viz.ui5.Scatter("mainCoyBubbleChart", { ....... Trying to use var mainCoyBubbleChart = new sap.viz.ui5.Bubble("mainCoyBubbleChart", { ..... retuns an empty chart